# What part of the Feeds api knows if there is a difference between old and new data?

Tags: feeds, flags

i want to flag an item if the feed has made any changes in a record.  What hook can I use to do a check of the new data and the old data to see if there is a difference?
I need to mark data that is changed with a flag and also get a log of all changed nodes.  Right now feeds seems to mark everything as updated even if there is no change.

I tried looking in hook_feeds_presave, but both the $item and the $entity are already changed there.  What hook can see a comparison between the old and the new ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am modifying the code in hook_feeds_before_update and writing the code like this :

```
if ($item){
    $node = node_load($item);
    $changed=false;

      if ($entity['ITEM'] != $node->field_item[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']){
         if (trim($entity['ITEM'])=="UNKNOWN"){
             $entity['ITEM'] = $node->field_item[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

         }

      }
```

AND then I flag it with a rule :

```
{ "rules_flag_when_updated_by_feed" : {
"LABEL" : "Flag when updated by feed",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "flag", "feeds" ],
"ON" : { "feeds_import_csv_importer" : [] },
"DO" : [
  { "flag_flagnode" : {
      "flag" : "flag_asset_for_review",
      "node" : [ "node" ],
      "flagging_user" : [ "site:current-user" ],
      "permission_check" : "1"
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

Comment: and then I flag it with a rule